# InfiniteContainer slow down in loading the content

Tags: codenameone

is anyone noticed InfiniteContainer performance slow down to load the content. I did see a significant lag in loading the content. Please suggest.

Comment: You mean in a recent update or as we scroll down through the content? If the former then in which update did it start? In the simulator, device, does it happen with a simple hello world style demo?

Comment: This heppens in both scenarios and it happens on simulator and device.I started observing this since a month in debug builds. Please advise.

Comment: Does it happen with a hello world `InfiniteContainer` that just adds buttons? How do we reproduce this issue?